# Cannot install openCV in Raspberry Pi 3 model B+ where source list is Jessie

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-jessie, raspberry-pi-os

This is for the project the board is provided from our college
we are trying to install openCV on Raspberry Pi 3 model B+ but we cannot install cmake and openCv.

But we have encountered an error . one thing we found out that our source list download from jessie.

What are we supposed to do,  we are literally stuck we have tried `sudo update` and `sudo install` but still we can't is there any solution for this.

Comment: please separate your post into proper sentence structure

Answer (score 0):

The commands you should use is:

```
sudo apt update
```

And to check if there is an OpenCV in the repository you can list what pakages is in the repository:

```
sudo apt list opencv*
```

And then you can install it with:

```
sudo apt install <pakagename>
```